How to serialize subprocess.popen()
This is follow-on to Return output of subprocess.popen() in webserver.  I have a long running process that is kicked off by a Webserver call (running Django).
I'm using subprocess.popen() to spawn the process.  I figured out how I can save the stdout and retrieve it later.  But since this is a long-running process, I want the client to be able to cancel it.  But in order to do that, I need an instance of the popen() object.  But it is not serialiable, so I can't store it in a database or anywhere else?
Is there any other solution other that just storing it locally in a map in views.py?

"Is there any other solution other that just storing it locally in a map" That's probably the easiest way. You'll need application state that can be accessed by the view on subsequent calls (which doesn't necessarily need to be a map, but that data structure probably makes the most sense). One option would be to simply store the pid of the process and manage the subprocess this way, but the popen object is the more natural way to work with the resource. Take extra care to ensure you wait every popen, else you'll get a zombie subprocess leak.

Other options would be to use separate systems to manage your job queue, such as Jenkins, Argo, or Celery, and register the job id of the running task in your database after requesting execution on these systems. When you look to scale your service to multiple instances of servers, these tools allow you a way to manage/track jobs, even when requests to cancel a job land on different servers than the initial instance which issued the request.

We use a Workload Management System like pbsTorque, Oracle Grid engine, or Slurm. You submit a bash command to these systems and they manage running it on different nodes, furthermore, you can tell them where to save stdout and stderr. Also, you can write a dependency between the jobs like job 3 starts after job 1 and job 2 are completed successfully.
